# Manipulate and Rules inside Expressions

Tags: manipulate, rule

I'm not grokking the use of `Manipulate` when an expression contains Rules. This example works and throws no errors -

```
maxSol[a_] := FindMaximum[{Sin[x], {x > 0, x < a}}, {x, 1/2}]
fn[a_] := (x /. Last@maxSol[a])
Manipulate[
 maxSol[a],
 {{a, 1/2, "a"}, 1/10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

But it complains about the `Rule` from `FindMaximum` not being a `Rule`  when I do this,

```
maxSol[a_] := FindMaximum[{Sin[x], {x > 0, x < a}}, {x, 1/2}]
fn[a_] := (x /. Last@maxSol[a])
Manipulate[
 fn[a],
 {{a, 1/2, "a"}, 1/10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

because it somehow transforms the `Rule` into its replacement value only. I'm having a hard time understanding why `x` is affected by `Manipulate` when it is not a control variable.

Comment: It works fine for me (Mma 12.2, Win10)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on 12.1.1.0 on Mac. Image at the link: https://www.screencast.com/t/Ar8lrWoRsy

Comment: I upgraded to 12.2 from 12.1 and the error disappeared.

Comment: Thanks, [Alexei Boulbitch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/788/alexei-boulbitch), for doing the version check on Windows